# EF 4.1 Code First modify generated SQL query

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using EF Code First to perform queries on the database. However, I would like to modify the generated SQL commands by CF to add extra things to the SQL Server DB. Is it possible to change the final SQL query before it is executed ??

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this - can you elaborate on what kind of modifications you'd like to make to the SQL ?? Maybe there's another way to achieve this without modifying the EF generated queries...

Comment: I don't think so. I would like to execute an update like this: 

"; update Table set column=value where id=value"

Comment: and EF cannot do this for you??

Comment: I want to do it the efficient way in one round trip.